# Thai Chicken and Noodles Recipe Recreation

Tags: chicken, asian-cuisine, noodles, thai-cuisine

I used to eat this delicious Thai Chicken and Noodles recipe from a restaurant that closed down over a decade ago.  I'm looking for a closest approximation of a recipe that will still taste good. (I don't know if cooking.SE will tolerate this kind of question, since it's a bit off-topic, but here goes.)

The dish was composed of:

- Dark brown noodles, a bit thick
- Chicken that was reddish and deep-fried; it was very crispy
- Chopped vegetables; zucchini at the least.

The dish was pretty dry; it didn't have any curry, sauce, or any other ingredients, really.

How would I make a dish like this? Or, what's the closest to this dish that I can find a recipe for?

Comment: This sounds fairly simple and easy! Was the chicken breaded and spicy?  If so, was it a Panko type breading (Yum, Panko!) or maybe just some flour with Thai spices mixed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these recipes for curry fried chicken.  They look tasty.  Just use chicken breast cut into strips instead of whole legs and wings and things.

[This one](http://luxuryrecipes.blogspot.com/2011/04/crispy-curry-fried-chicken.html), or [this one](http://www.rachaelrayshow.com/food/recipes/crispy-curry-fried-chicken/).

They're the same recipe, but it makes me laugh that this site just copied Rachael Ray or vice verse :p.  Probably the former, but still amusing.  Anyway..

You should be able to find some whole grain rice noodles from most major grocers, least here in Cleveland, Ohio.  They will be thick like your looking for.  Start those boiling while you saute your veggies with some olive oil.  Start off with some garlic in the pan for a minute once it's hot, then add some green beans, bell peppers, zucchini, snow peas and what-have-you and cook until they are as tender as you would like.

Mix in the noodles, with an extra tablespoon (15mL) of olive oil if you please, and give them a toss. Put the chicken on top almost like a garnish.

If you think it will be too dry, it's easy to make a sauce REALLY quick by just reserving some of the water you used to cook the noodles, like 1/4 to 1/3 Cup, or 50 to 100mL (it's a really rough number).  Add the water to your noodles and veggies in small increments until you think it's "saucy" enough.  Add in some Curry Paste or eat as is!

Try using Peanut Oil or Sesame Oil instead of Olive Oil!